# How to use sweetalert2 in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Getting this error after npm start in angular project.

> app/app.component.ts(12,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'swal'.
>   app/app.component.ts(21,7): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'swal'.

I created an angular project. Inside app.component.ts I added sweet alert  code

```
export class AppComponent {
deleteRow() {
      swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    }).then(function() {
      swal(
        'Deleted!',
        'Your file has been deleted.',
        'success'
      );
    })
  }
}
```

I did

```
npm install sweetalert2 --save
```

and also added the path in index.html

```
<script src="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css">
```

Comment: try `declare var swal: any;` or install declaration file https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/sweetalert/sweetalert.d.ts

Comment: @yurzui thanks for the quick reply. where do i need to add this file ?

Comment: Actually if comment swal code and do npm install and after if i uncomment swal code it works.

Comment: You can add `declare var swal: any;` on top the file where you're using `swal(...`

Comment: Thanks now able to run but getting error in console "TypeError: swal is not a function" sweetalert is not showing

Comment: Check my sample http://plnkr.co/edit/3WS18o7baXN1uegyuJCc?p=preview

Comment: Thanks @yurzui . it is working now.

Comment: @yurzui thanks for your example. It worked for me with angular2.

Comment: use this link for better solution :: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57321486/using-sweetalert2-with-typescript-could-not-find-a-declaration-file-for-module/65578093#65578093

Answer (score 22):

Solution given by @yurzui is the only worked with angular2. I tried almost everything. Plunker may go away. i'm putting it here for others:

[**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/3WS18o7baXN1uegyuJCc?p=preview)

1) 
Add these css and js on top of your index.html

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://npmcdn.com/sweetalert2@4.0.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">

<script src="https://npmcdn.com/sweetalert2@4.0.15/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

2) Add this line to the component where you want to use swal.

```
declare var swal: any;
```

After these changes my swal namespace is available and i'm able to use it's features.

I did not import any `ng2-sweelalert2` or any other module.

Comment: This worked for me, as mentioned by Akash Rao and yurzui                  declare var swal : any                                                                               just below all import statements in the companent and then using the object init : swal({}) where needed.

Comment: What a LEGEND!! Thank you, this worked very well and is very clean.

Comment: This answer is now outdated: see my answer below or Velu S Gautam's one. SweetAlert2 has type definitions now (bundled in the lib), and the library can be imported as a module (`import swal from 'sweetalert2'`)

Comment: very useful tip

Answer (score 12):

NPM install SweetAlert2

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

You can add

```
import swal from 'swal'; 
//import swal from 'sweetalert2'; --if above one didn't work
```

in your component and you can start using like in your component.

```
swal({
  title: 'Error!',
  text: 'Do you want to continue',
  type: 'error',
  confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
})
```

You can use fat arrow to maintain this.

```
deleteStaff(staffId: number) {
     swal({
          type:'warning',
          title: 'Are you sure to Delete Staff?',
          text: 'You will not be able to recover the data of Staff',
          showCancelButton: true,
          confirmButtonColor: '#049F0C',
          cancelButtonColor:'#ff0000',
          confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
          cancelButtonText: 'No, keep it'
        }).then(() => {
        this.dataService.deleteStaff(staffId).subscribe(
          data => {
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('error')) {
              this.alertService.error(data.error);
            } else if (data.status) {
              swal({
                type:'success',
                title: 'Deleted!',
                text: 'The Staff has been deleted.',              
              })
            }
          }, error => {
            this.alertService.error(error);
          });
        }, (dismiss) => {
          // dismiss can be 'overlay', 'cancel', 'close', 'esc', 'timer'
          if (dismiss === 'cancel') {
            swal({
              type:'info',
              title: 'Cancelled',
              text: 'Your Staff file is safe :)'
            })
          }
        });
    }
```

In angular-cli.json

```
"styles": [
            "../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css"

        ],
"scripts": [
            "../node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js"
        ],
```

Comment: Where can I find `angular-cli.json`? I can't find them in codes generated by dotnet core. I also cannot find it on Angular 2 tutorial. By the way, the genererated codes use webpack. Is there any way to define this css and js on it?

Comment: angular-cli.json comes with the angular-cli installation. You can either statically define the css and js your application or copy the above files to your css and js folder, but you need to do that next time when you do npm update.

Comment: Statement `import swal from 'swal';` didn't worked for me. Instead I used `import swal from 'sweetalert2';`

Comment: WorkersComponent.html:33 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of undefined
    at SweetAlert (sweetalert2.js:2741)
    at WorkersComponent.deleteRecord (workers.component.ts:30)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (WorkersComponent.html:33)
    at handleEvent (core.js:23107)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:24177)
    at Object.debugHandleEvent [as handleEvent] (core.js:23904)
    at dispatchEvent (core.js:20556)
    at core.js:21003
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (platform-browser.js:993)
    a

Comment: this will not work . it should be     **import Swal from 'sweetalert2';**

Answer (score 8):

@user1501382's solution is very handy sometimes for pure-JavaScript packages that don't have type definitions, for example, and that was the case for SweetAlert2, until a few weeks ago.
Also, using the global `swal` variable isn't very neat and you can do much better.

Now that SweetAlert2 has type defintions, you can do:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2';

swal({ ... }); // then use it normally and enjoy type-safety!
```

<s>Also import SweetAlert's CSS file, via a `<link>` or whatever. When you use a module bundler like Webpack and you have css-loader and style-loader configured, you can also do something like:</s>

```
import 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.css';
```

***Edit***: this should not be necessary since SweetAlert2 v.7.0.0, which bundles the CSS build into the JavaScript, and injects the styles in the page at runtime.

Also, I'll let you discover my library, that provides Angular-esque utilities to use SweetAlert2 with ease and class: **[sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2](https://github.com/sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2)** (it is now the official SweetAlert2 integration for Angular)

Give it a try!

Answer (score 6):

**npm install sweetalert2**

You can try:

```
import swal from 'sweetalert2'; 

swal.fire('Hello world!')//fire
```

Answer (score 1):

First, install `sweetalert2`using `npm`.
Then `import Swal from 'sweetalert2'`

In `app.component.html`

```
<input type="button" value="Show Toast" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showToast()"/>

<input type="button" value="Show Message" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="showMessage()"/>
```

In `app.component.ts`

```
showToast(){
Swal.fire({ toast: true, position: 'top-end', showConfirmButton: false, timer: 3000, title: 'Success!', text: 'Sweet Alert Toast', icon: 'success', });
  }

  showMessage(){
    Swal.fire({ text: 'Hello!', icon: 'success'});
  }
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularwithsweetalerttoast?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

this is how i use it on my projects

```
npm install sweetalert2
```

after installing add swal to window

```
window.swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

thats all.
if you are having problem with css, just import the scss file

```
@import "node_modules/sweetalert2/src/sweetalert2";
```

or include the css file from the node_module directory