# Using SweetAlert2 with TypeScript, could not find a declaration file for module 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings, sweetalert2, javascript-import

I'm migrating one of my projects to TypeScript, in that project [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) library is used.

The default way to import SweetAlert2 (both JS and CSS) is

```js
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'
```

This works fine with TypeScript because there are types in the library: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/sweetalert2.d.ts

But in my project the way of importing is this:

```js
import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'
```

This is import for JS only, without styles. With this type of import, I'm getting the TS error:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'. 

ts(7016)
```

I tried to copy `sweetalert2/sweetalert2.d.ts` to `sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.d.ts`, but got another error:

```
File 'node_modules/sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.d.ts' is not a module. 

ts(2306)
```

What's going on here and why TS complains about `dist/sweetalert2.d.ts` is not a module?

Comment: I am using import Swal from 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js'; in my ts file with no error.

Comment: @SagarChaudhary I made a simple repo with minimal code to reproduce the issue: https://github.com/limonte/swal-ts Could you please take a look and maybe spot the difference between your project and `limonte/swal-ts`. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current type definitions of SweetAlert does not provide typings for "submodules".
When you use the `declare module` syntax [like this](https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/master/sweetalert2.d.ts#L1), you type the whole package "at once" (what an user gets when importing from `^sweetalert2$`), but you're not describing what's in the individual compiled files in dist/ exactly, so yes, they can't be targeted explicitly.

Try removing the `declare module` block entirely in your **copied** file. Then, use `declare namespace Swal`, and it'll work.

We should be able to modify the declaration files of sweetalert2 so both simple import and the import of sub-files work.

Take a look at how I typed graphql-compose so this becomes possible: [graphql-compose](https://github.com/graphql-compose/graphql-compose)

Each .js file has a .d.ts counterpart, and there is no longer one single file that describes the whole module with `declare module`.

Edit: I tried this approach in you repro, this works well, and we're able to type `sweetalert2.all.js` as well. The following solution may be simpler though (less files, simpler build scripts). The 1:1 mapping approach is better but is probably more suited to larger libraries.

Another possibility is to add `declare module 'sweetalert2/dist/{**}'` entries to the single `sweetalert2.d.ts` file, that reexports the default module contents for each `dist/` variant:

```
declare module 'sweetalert2' {
    // Current contents of the file, unchanged
}

declare module 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js' {
    export * from 'sweetalert2';
    // "export *" does not matches the default export, so do it explicitly.
    export { default } from 'sweetalert2';
}

declare module 'sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.all.js' {
    export * from 'sweetalert2';
    export { default } from 'sweetalert2';
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Morgan! For the record, the PR with the fix: https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/pull/1693

Answer (score 5):

I was facing same problem but i got my solution form your links [sweetalert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#download).

Follow the **USAGE** section.

```
i was using in import SWAl from "sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js".
```

that is working in new project but not in my old project. so i moved here and got my solution. just replaced by **sweetalert2/dist/sweetalert2.js** to **sweetalert2**

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
```

everyone need to also focus into this line. i removed css and js from **angular.json** file of sweetalert2.

check this steps

> projects -> architect -> test -> options -> styles:[] and scripts:[]